# Is there a way to set up a Azure Table Query in c# to fetch the most recent record?

Tags: azure-storage

I need to set up a TableQuery Filter condition so I can get the single most recently stored record. Is there an equivalent for Azure tables like SQL's "TOP"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure Table Design guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) refers "log tail pattern" to achieve this:
Log tail pattern - Retrieve the n entities most recently added to a partition by using a RowKey value that sorts in reverse date and time order.

Comment: Your reply did lead to the answer after a bit more searching. In the end the answer I was looking for was how to apply the TakeCount property of the TableQuery class.  For some reason the search function on the Azure Doc pages doesn't seem to consider the MSDN Azure SDK classes.